# Using 5-player combinations to find subset of a dataframe contain specific 5-player combinations, each column identifying one of the 5 players

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if the title is misleading, as I wasn't sure how to best explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm using NBA play by play data for the entire league this season to try and find relative defensive ratings for specific defensive lineups. Within the dataframe (df), there are columns for each offensive player, each defensive player, possessions, and points (there's a lot more but that's all I'm concerned with), so 10 columns total.

If I filter for a specific defensive combination, I have a smaller dataframe (df2) which is only information for when that defensive unit is on the floor. I've gotten this far already, but what I'm wanting to do now is take all of the offensive player combinations that this lineup has faced, and filter for that information in df.

So here's a much smaller example of what df2 might look like:

```
   offplayer1  offplayer2  offplayer3  offplayer4  offplayer5  defplayer1  defplayer2  defplayer3  defplayer4  defplayer5  possessions  points  
0           1           2           3           4           5          11          12          13          14          15            5       5 
1           1           2           3           4           6          11          12          13          14          15            4       4  
2           2           3           4           5           6          11          12          13          14          15            3       5
```

From this point, I'd want to take all of the combinations of offplayer1-5 in df2 and use that as a filter in df.

Any ideas on how best to do this?

Edit: here's the code for producing the above df2 and a sample df if you want it to demonstrate

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,5,5],[1,2,3,4,6,11,12,13,14,15,4,4],[2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,16,5,5],[1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23,24,25,10,10],[11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,5,5]]),columns=['offplayer1','offplayer2','offplayer3','offplayer4','offplayer5','defplayer1','defplayer2','defplayer3','defplayer4','defplayer5','possessions','points'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,5,5],[1,2,3,4,6,11,12,13,14,15,4,4],[2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,3,5]]),columns=['offplayer1','offplayer2','offplayer3','offplayer4','offplayer5','defplayer1','defplayer2','defplayer3','defplayer4','defplayer5','possessions','points'])
```

Comment: Can you provide an expected output based on your sample data? It is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm expecting another dataframe that's a subset of df, with only the offplayer1-5 from df2

Comment: I'm trying to create a better example in code if that explanation wasn't helpful enough... Sorry I know my explanation isn't great

Comment: Okay I added a sample df and df2... In my code I have a specific defensive lineup I'm looking at, so I use df.loc to filter for that in order to get df2... 

From there, that defensive lineup has faced many different offensive lineups... so I'm trying to take all of the offplayer1-5 combinations in df2 and then go back and use those as a filter in df, to see the performance of those offensive lineups versus the entire league... 

Did that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you should just be able to create a new index for each df based on the offplayer columns then `set_index` and use boolean indexing with `.isin`.  I modified your sample df slightly to show you.

```
# modified your sample data a little

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,5,5],
                            [1,2,3,4,6,11,12,13,14,15,4,4],
                            [1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,16,3,5],
                            [2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,5,5], 
                            [1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,17,5,5],
                            [1,2,3,4,7,11,12,13,14,17,5,5]]),
                  columns=['offplayer1','offplayer2','offplayer3','offplayer4','offplayer5',
                           'defplayer1','defplayer2','defplayer3','defplayer4','defplayer5',
                           'possessions','points'])

# def players your are looking for
defplayers = [11,12,13,14,15]

# create df2 through boolean indexing
df2 = df[df[df.columns[5:10]].isin(defplayers).all(1)]

# create new indices
df_idx = df.columns[:5].values.tolist()
df2_idx = df2.columns[:5].values.tolist()

# boolean indexing to filter df
df[df.set_index(df_idx).index.isin(df2.set_index(df2_idx).index)]
```